# Complex SQL String Comparison

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm merging two databases for a client. In an ideal world, I'd simply use the unique id to join them, but in this case the newer table has different id's.

So I have to join the tables on another column. For this I need to use a complex LIKE statement to join on the Title field. But... they have changed the title's of some rows which breaks the join on those rows.

How can I write a complex `LIKE` statement to connect slightly different titles?

For instance:

```
Table 1 Title = Freezer/Pantry Storage Basket
Table 2 Title = Deep Freezer/Pantry Storage Basket
```

or

```
Table 1 Title = Buddeez Bread Buddy
Table 2 Title = Buddeez Bread Buddy Bread Dispenser
```

Again, there are hundreds of rows with titles only slightly different, but inconsistently different.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

How far can MySQL Full-Text Search get me? Looks similar to Shark's suggestion in SQL Server.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  If it is SQL Server, it sounds like you'd have a huge benefit to utilizing Full Text Search (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

Comment: I'm using MYSQL. Thanks.

Comment: Well then I will take my leave on this question, I'm a SQL Server guy. :)  Good luck!

Comment: I haven't used SQL Servers Full Text Search before, but if it looks like it fits the bill you might consider downloading the free SQL Express and utilize it for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in stages.  First get all the ones that match out of the way so that you are only working with the exceptions.  Your mind is incredibly smarter than the computer in finding things that are 'like' each other so scan over the data and look for similarities and make sql statements that cover the specific cases you see until you get it narrowed down as much as possible.

You will have better results if you 'help' the computer in stages like this than if you try to develop a big routine to cover all cases at once.

Of course there are certainly apis out there that do this already (such as the one google uses to guess your search phrase before you finish it) but whether any are freely available I don't know.  Certainly wouldn't hurt to search for one though.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly difficult to describe ' only slightly different ' in a way that computer would understand. I suggest choosing a group of certain criteria that can be considered either most common or most important and work around it. I am not sure what those criteria should be though since i have only a vague idea what the data set looks like.